# Numpad in vim via ssh

Tags: ssh, vim, putty, numpad

I run putty in order to connect to Ubuntu machine via ssh. I found that when I use numpad in vim editor it prints garbage or executes some strange vim commands.

Why and how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `Vim` which enables Application Keypad Mode without defining any mappings for it.

Step 1: Open **PuTTY Configuration**  menu

Step 2: In the **left pane**(Category), select **Terminal**> **Features**.

Step 3: Select the checkbox along **Disable application keypad mode**.

Step 4: In the left pane, select **Session**.

Step 5: **Save** the settings for the session.

[image: screenshot]